# How can I organized work with class with the indexer?

Tags: c#, indexer

My task:
Create an array of dimension 10 elements, fill it with arbitrary integer values.
Print the max value of the array, the min value of the array, the total sum of the elements, the average of all elements, print all odd values.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;    

namespace Massiv
{
    public class MyMassiv
    {
        private int[] myMassiv = new int[10];
        public int this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return myMassiv[index];
            }
            set
            {
                myMassiv[index] = value;
            }
        }
        public int GetMaxElement(MyMassiv massiv)
        {            
            return myMassiv.Max();  
        }

        public int GetMinElement(MyMassiv massiv)
        {
            return myMassiv.Min();
        }

        public int GetSum(MyMassiv massiv)
        {
            return (int)myMassiv.Sum();
        }

        public double GetAverage(MyMassiv massiv)
        {
            return myMassiv.Average();
        }

        public void PrintOddValue(MyMassiv massiv)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myMassiv.Length; i++)
            {
                if(myMassiv[i] % 2 != 0)
                    Console.Write(myMassiv[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyMassiv mm = new MyMassiv();
            Random rnd = new Random();

            int n = 10;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                mm[i] = rnd.Next(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", i, mm[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Max: {0}, Min: {1}, Sum: {2}, Average: {3}", mm.GetMaxElement(mm), mm.GetMinElement(mm), mm.GetSum(mm), mm.GetAverage(mm));
            Console.Write("Odd Value: ");
            mm.PrintOddValue(mm);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }        
    }
}
```

It works, but I'm not sure about some of the designs. For example: "mm.GetMaxElement(mm)". This design seems imperfect to me. In class MyMassiv I am accessing a private int[] myMassiv - is it so good? What is my design error?
I think about designing methods so that nothing is passed on to them. Am I on the right track?

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. Why are you using indexers/a full class? Most of this sounds like a simple array and some static function could deal with it. Min/Max/Average stuff sounds like things that come months before any "use custom indexers" classes.

Comment: The main worry should be that you pass a parameter to each function, but you do not use it at all. So don't pass the parameter.

Comment: oerkelens, thank you! I just fixed it. I am accessing a private int[] myMassiv -  is it a safe treatment array?In reality, the array will be about 10 million values. The main task of the analysis of these 10 million values is to calculate the standard deviation from some function. 100 sets of values of, 364 functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on refactored example:

```
public class MyMassiv
{
    private int[] _array;
    public int MaxElement => _array.Max();
    public int MinElement => _array.Min();
    public int Sum => _array.Sum();
    public double Average => _array.Average();

    public MyMassiv(int size = 10)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        _array = Enumerable.Range(0, size)
            .Select(i => rnd.Next(1000))
            .ToArray();
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetOddValues() => _array.Where(item => item % 2 != 0);
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyMassiv mm = new MyMassiv();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Max: {0}, Min: {1}, Sum: {2}, Average: {3}",
            mm.MaxElement, 
            mm.MinElement, 
            mm.Sum,
            mm.Average);

        Console.Write("Odd Values: ");
        mm.GetOddValues()
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

You can encapsulate all 'logic' within scope of MyMassiv class.
In the main method you can only display values.
There is no need to pass MyMassiv object to the methods (like it was in your example).

Comment: I have not thought about this approach, now I will use it. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is very useful!

Comment: Thank you :) I would be grateful If you accept my answer